# Getting a 'JavaScript engine reported an unexpected error' on such a simple function

Tags: google-apps-script

I have searched for an answer to this problem but have been unsuccessful.

Reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528655/google-apps-script-randomly-produces-error-message-unexpected-error-occurred-a) I proceeded to comment out every single other function other than the function that has a trigger associated to it and I am getting the following error:

> Error We're sorry, the JavaScript engine reported an unexpected error.
> Error code INTERNAL.

```
function CELLARDWELLER_TRIGGER(e) {

  console.log('changeType: ', e.changeType);

  var ss0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet0 = ss0.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  console.log('Sheet: ', sheet0);

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web App call fails with "... Error code INTERNAL" with Custom API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967246/web-app-call-fails-with-error-code-internal-with-custom-api)

Comment: @KenY-N no it doesn't, I tried manually executing the function above and all I get is `Cannot read property 'changeType' of undefined` since `e` hasnt been passed, I do not get a permissions prompt either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are not alone facing this, whole lot of people are facing the same issue.

Check it out on Google's official tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184759540

And it seems to be resolved now, as I am getting successful triggers running after 11:10 AM IST.
[image]

Comment: It is NOT resolved.  I got this error yesterday, April 20, 2021.  At the very least, when this error occurs Google needs to rerun the application(s) in question until they succeed.  This is no way to run an airline.

Comment: This might be the primary issue of this type: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184664889